# Display columns dynamically based on drop down SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have to create a report in SSRS based on some fields. One of the requirements is that the columns of the report should be displayed dynamically based on the value of the selection field. The drop down is multi-select so the user can select which columns he wants to view.

```
--------------
|Col1,Col2 |V|
--------------

--------------------------
Col1        | Col2       |
--------------------------
```

I was thinking of using a `matrix` to display the columns but I'm not sure if they work on a drop down. Can this be done? Is there another way to show the columns like `Show/Hide Columns based on Expression`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use column visibility expression like that:
    =IIF(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!MultiValueParam.Value,"ColumnToShowName")>-1,False,True)